# '<' not supported between instances of 'node' and 'node' priorityqueue python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, priority-queue, a-star

I am implementing A* Search algorithm in Python.

for get the min edge node, i am using priority queue class of python. the algorithm implementation portion.

the code -

```
from queue import PriorityQueue



def a_star_search(g_edge, h_value, des):
    path = []

    class node:
        def __init__(self, node_no, prev, actual_cost, total_cost):
            self.node_no = node_no
            self.prev = prev
            self.actual_cost = actual_cost
            self.total_cost = total_cost

    minQ = PriorityQueue()
    new = node(0, None, 0, 10)
    minQ.put(new)
    path.append(0)
    while not minQ.empty():
        NOb = minQ.get()
        if NOb.node_no == des:
            return path

        for list in g_edge:
            for element in list:
                if element[0] == NOb.node_no:
                    prev = NOb.node_no
                    actual_cost = NOb.actual_cost + element[2]

                    for l in h_value:
                        if l[0] == 0:
                            total_cost = NOb.actual_cost + l[1]

                    NObNew = node(element[1], prev, actual_cost, total_cost)
                    minQ.put(NObNew)
                    path.append(NOb.node_no)
```

the error occured in this line ->

> NObNew = node(element[1], prev, actual_cost, total_cost)

where is the problem?

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ that the error occurred on that line, and not on `minQ.put(NObNew)`?

Comment: yes. google colab interpreter caught it